# Issue with soundPool.load Context

Tags: android, audio, android-context, soundpool

I have a Button in my app that calls an Async task.
This Async task should play audio files, on every ProgressUpdate.
I figured out quite a lot so far, but I am stuck with this:

i call

```
        this.strengthSound[0] = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.strength0,1);
        this.strengthSound[1] = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.strength1,1);
        this.strengthSound[2] = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.strength2,1);
        this.strengthSound[3] = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.strength3,1);
        this.strengthSound[4] = this.soundPool.load(this, R.raw.strength4,1);
```

to fill an array with the strengthx.mp3 s.

Anyway: I get an error with "this" in the load statement:

```
Error:(165, 57) error: incompatible types: AIM_start.start_AIM cannot be converted to Context
```

What context do I have to use with this soundPool.load(Context, ResourceID, ..) ?

Thanks for the help in advance... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Context mContext;

onCreate(...) {
    mContext = this;
}


// inside your AsyncTask 
...

    onProgressUpdate(int progress) {
      this.strengthSound[0] = this.soundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.strength0,1);
      ...
    }
```

I forgot the actual method signatures for AsyncTasks but this is basic rundown. You are misusing `this`.

`this` in your activity and `this` in your AsyncTask is different. `this` in AsyncTask refers to itself, which is AsyncTask, but `this` in your onCreate refers to (again) itself, which is the Activity itself.

Not sure if this helps, but feel free to elaborate on comment :)